# Remove files with a string in a bucket google cloud storage in python

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I'm working with google cloud storage and have several files uploaded to a bucket with similar names. Each file has the following format: `company_tile_lc_date1_today.tif`, where `today` is the date when the file was created and uploaded to the bucket. I also have files with this format: `company_tile_lcpr_date1_today.tif`. I need to remove all files as the first one (contains string `_lc_`) but keep the others. I have found several solutions using python and google cloud storage, all of them using `blob.delete`, however I haven't found a way to specify the string that has to have the file to remove. I know I can use the `prefix` parameter, but that's to specify the folder, not the files.

I also need to delete all files where `today` is before some specific date, I guess that knowing how to know the first part, this part would be similar.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [There aren't actually any "folders" in cloud storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders).  Maybe prefix will work for you given that it just matches the name of an object regardless of where they appear to be organized.

Comment: Your app will need to list the objects in the bucket. Then sort, filter, etc, and decide which files to delete.